# Seg fault with strtok

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, strtok

Hey guys I'm getting a seg fault with strtok, just need a little bit of help!

```
char s[1024];
char *token[2];
while(fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) != NULL) // Read line from file fp until end
{
    token[0] = strtok(s, "\t\n");
    token[1] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n");
    token[2] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n");
    printf("%d:%s:%d", atoi(token[0]), token[1], atoi(token[2]));
}
```

But I get a seg fault after the first passover of the loop.
The input file reads something like this:

```
102910319    code    mark
.
.
.
104981851    code    mark
```

But the while loop only prints the first line correctly and seg faults on the second line.

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: my first guess: you declared `token[2]` but you access 3 elements

Comment: also possible, after you fix the array declaration you may have data problems: - the white characters between columns are other than \t.

Comment: Fixed but still get the seg fault! 
@jimmcnamara Nope, they are all \t (tabs).

Comment: For `token[1]` and `token[2]`, do we require `\t\n` or only `\t` is sufficient as the delimiter?

Comment: You code will segfault on non \t whitespace characters. Because you will have NULL returned early. token[2] could be NULL for example.  Check the output of the command:  od -c inputfile | more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jack said, token is declared to store two `char *`s: `token[0]` and `token[1]`. `token[2]` is out of range. The solution to this is to change your declaration of token: `char *token[3];`.

Additionally, it could be that you've provided less than three "words" of input somewhere, in which the `%s` will tell printf to print a string pointed to by a null pointer, or the second `atoi` call will attempt to dereference a null pointer. The solution is to check `token[1]` before passing it to printf, and `token[2]` before passing it to `atoi`: `printf("%d:%s:%d", atoi(token[0]), token[1] ? token[1] : "null", token[2] ? atoi(token[2]) : 0);`

Alternatively, it looks like scanf might be more suitable for this:

```
int x, y;
char str[1024];
while (scanf("%d %1023s %d", &x, str, &y) == 3) {
    printf("%d:%s:%d\n", x, str, y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue. It was that the provided text file for input had an error where one of the 'tabs' was actually a few spaces. Fixed it up and voila it works!

Comment: @Travv92 The scanf code I posted would successfully handle repetitive tabs, spaces and newlines (in any combination)... Hence, I believe scanf would be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Array indexing problem.

You should declare the array of pointers as follows,

```
char *token[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it

```
char *token[2]
```

it can only allocate two char pointer not three.